# What was the purpose of the "naughty" words list?

Tags: mindhunter-2017

In episode 3 of the "Mindhunters", Holden and his fellow teacher talk about the "deviant terminology":

> **Holden** - I've, uh, done a bit of thinking about some of the things that we're teaching. In particular, the list of deviant terminology. 
>   **Kenneth** - The cuss words? Right. 
>   **Holden** -Well, I was thinking more the - descriptors of the acts.
>   - Uh You know, fellatio, cunnilingus[...] That's just it, Ken. I don't have an issue. I really don't know that they are deviant.
>   **Kenneth** - And you think we should alter the curriculum? Just take a look at the list.

In the next scene we can see Holden redacting this list:

[image]

I understand,  that the "Mindhunters" series takes place in the 70s, so I the social norms are different than the current ones, but I still fail to get the purpose of this list: Initially I thought that it was supposed to describe the "deviant acts" - hence removing the words describing oral sex means that those acts are now no longer treated as "perverted". But then we can see words like "ass" - which while not particularly polite, it is definitely not used only by deviants.

So what was the actual purpose of the list? Were those words that teachers weren't allowed to use? Please remember, that they are teaching the future FBI agents, who will deal with murderers and rapists on a daily basis, so I'm fairly sure they will hear worse on the job

Edit:

I've found this fragment in episode 1:

> **Holden** - When I started at the Academy, they would send women out of the room if there was any of that talk.
>   They called it "deviant terminology.
>   " We even had a list of words we had to memorize. [...] You know fuck, shit, pussy blow job.

So does it mean that this list is only used to "protect" the female agents?

Comment: Without any proof from the show runners, my thoughts from a more psychological perspective would be that they would want to avoid using words that may trigger some sort of unwanted behaviour or thought. Now to why words like "fuck, cunt, and dick" may still be used my only thought is opinion based and that is because they are still harsh and can be said without inciting purely sexual desire. While words like "cunnilingus, fellatio, and masturbation" are more explicitly sexual, and may accidentally distract the suspect from a line of questioning.

Comment: @user61979  who would trigger this "unwanted behaviour"? Students? Suspects? I'm not following - you might say "ass" in absolutely non-sexual meaning ("My boss is such an ass!") but words like "fellatio" are scientific terms for a sexual act - you don't use them in casual discussion.

Comment: Exactly, terms like "ass" are not always sexual. So I am saying that the suspects may get taken off task, or it would trigger unwanted behaviour from a suspect, when an agent would bring up these explicitly sexual terms. Similarly to the way that when Holden is interviewing the serial killers, he is told not to bring up certain things. Or bring in objects that may trigger memories from the killers. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @Stevibob not really. 1. An agent would rather ask the suspect about "blow-job" rather than "fellatio" because suspect most likely wouldn't understand the term. 2. An agent wouldn't causally talk about it - when he would ask about such things, it would be because he **needs to know the answer**, like "have you been forced to perform fellatio"